# Role of capacitor in PCB of hand blender

Tags: pcb, capacitor

While re-soldering the loose wires of our immersion blender, I found a 310V, 100pF capacitor. Is it for filtering the DC or is it for giving the instance response property to the gadget.

Comment: Where was the capacitor connected in the circuit?

Comment: I doubt it is for the "instance response," because of it's size. However it does depend where in the circuit it is. Based on its voltage tolerance it is probably just used to cancel noise or help stabilize a regulator, etc.

Comment: What is a 'house blender'? I'd stay away from that.

Comment: The internal circuitry of the blender is mostly a motor and a small PCB. On the PCB are soldered the wires that connect to the mains supply and a small capacitor.

Comment: Part of transformerless DC power supply?

Comment: Sensitive gate Triacs need a small RF cap to prevent false triggering

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: this is possibly a snub capacitor for bypassing a transient voltage spike when the motor is shut off, or the EMI generated by sparking brush contacts.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is start-up cap for the motor to make it spin the correct way. But hard to say for sure as the question doesn't have enough detail.

Although looking online it seems like a lot of blender motors are DC motors. In that case, my vote is for EMI filtering (which would match the 100pF size better).

Comment: I seriously doubt that 100 pF would cause any appreciable phase shift as a startup capacitor would need to.  That's a few orders of magnitude too small.

Comment: yeah I agree. Probably DC motor and just a filter.